# Assigning a unique number in env inside each pod in a kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster inside which there will be some pods running. For each pod I want to assign a unique id as env variable. eg: pod 1 server_id= 1, pod 2 server_id=2 etc.
Anyone have any idea how this can be done. I am building my docker image and deploying to cluster through gitlab ci.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Adding ENV variables into helm or YAML template**

You can add a variable to the YAML file and apply it as per the requirement if your deployment are different.

**Get the variables values into POD and use it**

Or else you can get the POD name of deployment that will be different from each other and if you are fine to use that which will be unique

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-envars-fieldref
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - while true; do
          echo -en '\n';
          printenv MY_NODE_NAME MY_POD_NAME MY_POD_NAMESPACE;
          printenv MY_POD_IP MY_POD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT;
          sleep 10;
        done;
      env:
        - name: MY_NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: MY_POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: MY_POD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.serviceAccountName
  restartPolicy: Never
```

If you want to set your own **variable** and **values** you have to use the different deployment.

if you want to manage the **sequence** you need to use the **stateful sets**.

Sequence something like

```
POD-1
POD-2
POD-3
```

as environment variables at the, you want just this you can use stateful sets POD name and get value from node and inject back to POD and application use it further.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
Yes I am trying to add my own variable. I want to assign a unique id as env variable ( say 1,2,3 ) for a pod and its replica.  I have only worked with deployment object for now. Will checkout `stateful sets` as you mentioned

Comment: if it's just about unique variable you want then you can use deployment which will create a `random POD name` and you can use that POD name as a variable. as shared above printenv getting data from node or env.

Comment: I want it to be an integer and not random. Say there are 5 pods. Then the id should be 1,2,3,4,5. When a pods pod fails and another one is created id value should not be more than 5 and should also be unique ( So if 3 fails and when new is created it should have value 3 as well).

Comment: checkout the statefulsets i think it will work or else you can use different deployment.

Comment: Thank you Harsh. I worked it out using statefulsets.