# Make all Kubernetes pods listen to the same Kafka topic

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, apache-kafka, event-handling

#### Situation

- We have multiple Kubernetes pods of each deployment (= microservice)
- Our application is massively Kafka-based
- Normally each microservice consumes each Kafka topic in a single consumer group, which is good as we need that each Kafka events is consumed exactly once
- Kubernetes launches and stops pods whenever it's needed

#### Problem

- We have one topic, which must be consumed by all the running instances (pods) of a single microservice (to reset some internal status)

### What we considered and why it doesn't work

- Consume from the topic always in a new consumer group with a random name:
  NO, because as soon as a pod is killed, the consumer group remains for ever, with the constantly increasing lag. The number of detached consumer group without a listener grows over time.
- [Assigning a unique number in env inside each pod in a kubernetes cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69717216/2886891):
  NO, because we use ReplicaSet and not StatefulSet

### Requirements (summary)

- All the events from one particular topic must be consumed by each running instance of the microservice, i.e. by each pod of one particular deployment.
- Kubernetes uses ReplicaSet, the names of the pods have random a string appended.
- No zombie consumer groups are allowed.

### Question

- How to solve it, either in Kafka or in Kubernetes or anywhere outside or around or in the middle of it?

Comment: I have little knowledge on those topics but maybe something like the 1st solution (consumer group with a random name) using Kubernetes [PreStop hook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/) to delete the consumer group. Looks like consumer groups [can be automatically deleted](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka/operations-tools/manage-consumer-groups.html#view-consumer-group-info) but I don't really know how it works.

Comment: Is there an available hook when when a pod is created/killed?  If yes, on creation, programmatically add a new topic subscription and start listening on that subscription.  And on kill, programmatically delete the subscription.

Answer (score 2):

> the consumer group remains for ever

If you don't commit the offsets, then no group is created.

> constantly increasing lag

This is only an issue if you use `auto.offset.reset=earliest`.

> All the events from one particular topic must be consumed by each running instance of the microservice

You can use `consumer.assign()` with the list of TopicPartition, which you can query with `AdminClient`, or hard-code.

Otherwise, you need to use a random group per pod since any static value will cause idle consumers when there are more pods than partitions.

Also, you are not required to use Kafka `__consumer_offsets` topic at  all. You can manually commit offset values in an external store, and use `assign` and `seek` functions. When you use an external store, then you can have better guarantees of exactly-once processing since you can additionally mark any offset as "processed==true", and seek to the min(processed == false) offset before each seek.